# Painting a chessboard

Tags: checkerboard

On the following chessboard every white square meets at least two red squares.

[image]

Let's paint a new chessboard so that every white square meets *exactly* two red square. Every square should be painted either red or white. It is clearly possible from the following chessboard.

[image]

But, too many squares were painted red. What is the minimal number of squares should be painted red?

Comment: Maybe specify that all squares must be painted either red or white. Otherwise there's a [solution with zero](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=03mUI9LaaIg#t=25).

Comment: Since each red square can touch at most four white squares, a lower bound is (# red) ≥ (# white) / 2, so (# red) ≥ 22.

Comment: @Bass OK. I added the phrase.

Comment: What about diagonals?  If two squares' corners touch diagonally, are the squares themselves considered to touch?

Comment: It would be interesting to see how this evolves depending on the size of the chess board.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I can do

> 29

like so:

> [image]

The pattern might be even prettier than that of [@hexomino's answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/102323/36023). :-)

EDIT: sadly, no circle pattern anymore, but scores **n**one better: (RE-EDIT: bold letter added because of Jaap's keen eyes; h3 must be red)

> 28:
>  [image]

And another one with the same amount of redness (RE-EDIT: my only decent solution), this time with more boring symmetry (and also optimal if we are to trust @2012rcampion's comment below):

> [image]

Comment: Oooh, very nice! +1

Comment: I think your second solution is the best possible (based on my computer results).

Comment: Your first solution of 28 is incorrect. The white square in row 5 column 8 has only one red neighbour. When you fix that, it is essentially your first 29 solution rotated 180 degrees. Your symmetric solution looks correct.

Comment: I confirmed via integer linear programming that 28 is optimal.

Comment: Thank you very much @JaapScherphuis! (and also the computer solvers!)

Comment: For $n\in\{1,\dots,17\}$, the optimal values are $\{1,2,5,8,11,17,21,28,35,42,51,60,69,80,91,102,115\}$, from which I conjecture general formula $\lceil (n+2)^2/3 \rceil - 6$ for $n \ge 7$.

Comment: @Bass Right. 28 is the answer. There are two more patterns other than yours when symmetries are taken into accounts.

Comment: @RobPratt Oh, thank you for your search. Is it possible to check the number of solutions? I just know that 8x8 board has exactly 3 solutions and 9x9 board has a unique solution.

Comment: @P.-S.Park Here are the counts for $n\in\{1,\dots,10\}$, ignoring symmetry: $1, 2, 5, 4, 2, 16, 2, 8, 2, 8$

Comment: @RobPratt Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

Not sure if this is minimal but there is a nice symmetric solution for

> $32$ red squares

as follows

> [image]

Comment: Depending on how you look at it, the answer could also be 88.

Answer (score 2):

OP's comment.

When I propose this problem, many people used to hand in the following patterns with 32 red squares.

> [image]

That's a beautiful symmetric pattern. But, they are not a minimal answer. This problem was proposed to deceive people who were satisfied with the symmetric solutions. :-)

The correct answers with 28 red squares are as follows:

> [image]

Note that Quadrants II and IV are symmetric and Quadrants I and III on each pattern are mixed with 2 types. So, ignoring symmetry, the total number of solutions of 28 red squares is 8 as commented by RobPratt.

The minimal answer for $9 \times 9$ board is a pattern with 35 red squares.

> [image]

This pattern is symmetric, so the total number of solutions is just 2 as also commented.

Comment: questions shoule be left open  for more than 24 hours before the OP posts a spoiler.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that. I'll delete my spoiler.

Comment: I undeleted after 24 hours.